# wpf styles are not applied on dynamically added elements

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

my project use  richtextbox control which can be save and restore from rtf file, but i found my style not applied on restored elements (indent of bullet item and image ), here i write a simpliest demo to reproduce my problem:

**1. at first, write any string in richtextbox and list it:**

[image]

**2. click save button to save richtextbox content to rtf file**

**3. clear richtextbox content**

**4. click restore button to restore data from rtf file,content will changed as :**

[image]

it seems set `Padding` property not work on restored item,why? and how to solve it?

all codes are as follows:

- mainwindow.xaml

```xml
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Paragraph">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="List">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"></Setter>
        </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Toggle</Button>
        <Button Click="save">save</Button>
        <Button Click="restore">restore</Button>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="richtextbox"></RichTextBox>
       
    </StackPanel>
```

- backend code:

```cs
 private void save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextRange tr = new TextRange(richtextbox.Document.ContentStart, richtextbox.Document.ContentEnd);
            using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("D:/test.rtf", FileMode.Create)) 
            {
                tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
                ms.Flush();
            }
        }

        private void restore(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("D:/test.rtf", FileMode.Open))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                richtextbox.SelectAll();
                richtextbox.Selection.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
            }
           
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EditingCommands.ToggleBullets.Execute(null, richtextbox);
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to use  `FileMode.Xaml` or `FileMode.XamlPackage`? Seems like _Save_/_Load_ context of the RichTextBox for the `FileMode.Rtf` mode does not work correctly.

Comment: @Victor yes, i tried xamlpackge, it works fine, i changed to this mode